# Function execution freezes GUI despite using Threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I have my very simple GUI built with tkinter containing a progress bar which should show program activity during long processing function. As I understand I have to use threads as tkinter is single threaded so I wrote following code:

```
def start(self):
    self.root.progressbar.start(interval=5)
    try:
        path = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile='log.txt', filetypes=[("Text file", "*.txt")],
                                               initialdir='~/Desktop')
        if path:
            filtering_thread = FilteringThread(self.comparator)
            filtering_thread.run()
            self.root.progressbar.stop()
            self.comparator.log_matches(path)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Choose path to save result.")

    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", str(e))
```

And here is my FilteringThread implementation:

```
class FilteringThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, comparator):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.comparator = comparator

    def run(self):
        import time
        for _ in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
            print("IN THREAD")
```

As for now it just mimics the behavior of a real function but the idea stays the same. I should see in the console that it prints "IN THREAD" 5 times while to progress bar should bounce around the GUI.

But it doesn't work: could anyone point me an error that I am making? I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `filtering_thread.run()` in your function, thus calling the `run()` function of your thread object *in the current thread*.  This is why you don't have anything threaded in your program.

Instead, you need to call `filtering_thread.start()`.  This will return immediately but will have started a new thread which then will execute the thread object's `run()` function.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea, but where should I invoke run() funtion then? Inside star() function? It still works the same. Could you please provide some example code?

Comment: If you call the `start()` function, the thread class you inherit will start an (operating system) thread which will run the `run()` function.  You never call the `run()` function yourself.